# C# application using Wia on dotnet 2.0 appear to use Wia not in dotnet 2.0

Tags: .net, com, com-interop, wia

I have a strange problem.
I create a little DLL in C# in order to drive some scanners with WIA.

I added as reference the WIA Com object.
In my property project, i setted up the framework version to dotnet 2.0 ( and i need to run on 2.0).

My problem is that when i use my dll, it appear that WIA object is trying to run on the dotnet 2.0

For more explanation, i call my dll from a proprietary software which can run only dotnet 2.0 application, and when i call my dll it tell my a components is trying to run with a dotnet > 2.0.

Is there a way to force the dll using wia com under dotnet 2.0 ? Or maybe i need to use an older Interop.Wia.dll ?

I run this application on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.
I used the famous Ilmerge tool in order to merge my dll and the Interop.wia.dll.
I added the **/targetplatform:v2** on the ilmerge commandLine. All is ok now :)